# Exception while running the batch using File System Adapter

Tags: service, adapter, ax, aif

I am getting an error " There is no service with namespace = ' http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services' and external name = 'ItemService' while running the batch using file system adapter. I went to different forums and as per the suggestions I made sure that the name of the namespace is correct in the services node in the AOT. I am not being able to understand why the system is not able to find the service with the given namespace. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One cause of this problem can be an extra slash at the end of your namespace on the service node. 
Remove it and it should work, as I describe here: [AIF: There is no service with namespace = ‘http://yournamespace’ and external name = ‘aService’.](http://www.artofcreation.be/2011/04/27/aif-there-is-no-service-with-namespace-httpyournamespace-and-external-name-aservice/)

You might also want to do a refresh in the services form and a redeploy of your services after that.